# Laravel queryBuilder wired behavior using search by id

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I'm try to find answer for this wired behavior
so in db I have record with id =14
when I add some random chars to find its return the record with id = 14

```
 User::query()->find('14fdsf')
```

normaly its should be return null  !! any ideas why that happen ??

Comment: because `14 == (int) '14fdsf'` ... the type (string) is being juggled to an int some where; would be my guess

Comment: yeah yeah exactly , I forget that !!! thanks

Comment: It appears that this type conversion happens at the database level. I don't see anywhere in the query builder code where it casts to an integer. The database I'm using (mysql) does document this [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html). I would assume you're using mysql or your database has a similar behavior. If you're curious like I was, you can verify this yourself by logging the query Laravel generates. You'll see that the string is still present in the bindings.

Answer (score -1):

Laravel is translating your string into an integer.

'14fdsf' = (int) 14

You should only use an integer when doing a ->find(int) query.

Comment: There's a couple issues here. 1) Laravel is not doing any translating. I was curious, so I checked. The type coercion is happening at the database level. 2) Although rare and unadvisable in most cases, you can have a primary key that is not an integer. So the last piece of advice is not always true.